# Basic PHP Register / Profile Page

Tags: php, web

I was wondering if anybody could show me a pretty decent and basic PHP Register form page that saves a profile page in to the database.

I was going to use it to try and build off to make a more advanced one as I'm trying to get better with PHP.

If you could show me one and explain a little bit of it that would be great.

Comment: A very nice, practical question. I don't agree to those downvoting and voting to close it. It can be considered rhetorical but can have some very practical answers. There are many cases when using a 3-rd party framework/engine seems an overkill for your simple site and reasonable no-bloat code snippet can turn the most adequate solution. Moreover, such a clean solution can be a good subject to explore security risks and hardening measures possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Basic PHP Register / Profile Page**

http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?265799-Login-amp-Registration-form-with-profile

make a member.php like a profile template and create an url like bellow when user finished the registration

```
$profileUrl = http://www.yousite.com/members.php?user='.$userId;
```

generate a user id when any user finished the registration and get the userId usiong $_GET

In members.php

```
$userId = $_GET['userId'];
```

and get the user details from the database according to the user id .that's it

In members.php

```
$userId = $_GET['userId'];

include('your database class file');

$sth = $dbconnect->prepare("SELECT first_name,last_name FROM register WHERE userId = :userId");
$params = array("userId" => $userId);
$sth->execute($params);

$status = $sth->fetchAll();
```

Use it like above.Create your own codes for additional details to fetch from the database

Comment: Thanks! This helped kinda, although do you know how I would make it so that in the members.php file I could have a variable for their username to have their own user-page. like members.php?user=3 for example. Any ideas?

Comment: So could you give me an example of what the members.php file would look like? I understand how to make it save userID to the database after registering though.

Comment: Update buddy,it take time to create the code in full.but this sound good for starting